# Completed emails showing on draft list

Tags: civimail

We've got 27 emails that show as completed, have a report, etc; however, they are showing on the list of Draft/Unscheduled emails. What could be causing this to happen? I'm trying to clean up the back-end for the new volunteers who will be working with the site this year, but I don't want to delete emails that have actually been sent.

We're on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.5.3

[image: CiviCRM screenshot]

Comment: Is this on CiviMail report or Activity report?

Comment: If this is in CiviMail - what checkboxes are checked in the Mailing Status box for each menu item (Draft and Unscheduled Mailings vs. Scheduled and Sent Mailings)?

Comment: It's the page you get when your select the Unscheduled and Draft link under the Mailings menu item. 

The only thing checked is the one for unscheduled and drafts or whatever it's called (sorry, don't have it right in front of me at the moment). Only a couple dozen out of hundreds of sent emails are showing on that page.

Comment: Now that I'm at the computer, I grabbed a screenshot to show where it's at and what is clicked.

Comment: The screenshot is helpful - is see it's not respecting that 'draft / unscheduled' checkbox. Since it's only a couple dozen, maybe you can take a look in the database itself, see if there is some other value that these share but not the other completed mailings that aren't showing. (Also I see that the created by is blank on the couple shown in the screenshot - theoretically that should have nothing to do with it - but it's strange there's no contact listed maybe that's affecting things?)

Answer (score 2):

I just verified that a completed mailing (in my test installation of 5.5.3) will show up  in the draft/unscheduled list IF the original creator of the email is a deleted (permanently) user. Doesn't solve the problem but at least gives us a cause.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I can go into the database and add a user to them. I've told folks not to remove people, just change their permission level.

Comment: I didn't fully test it someone who was only partially deleted (still recoverable). Maybe there's a chance you can restore the original contact. If not, I agree you should just be able to assign it directly in the database to make that connection again and pull them off the report.

Comment: I think they completely deleted the person, plus I'd have no idea who it was. I just assigned them all to my user account since it's easy to just input 1 as the user who did it. Now they're all gone from that list. :D

Comment: Yay! Glad it all worked out!